# Python Regular Expression from File

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract lines following some sequence from a file. E.g. a file contains many lines and I want line in sequence

```
journey (a,b) from station south chennai to station punjab chandigarh
journey (c,d) from station jammu katra to city punjab chandigarh
journey (e) from station
```

let's say above is the code and I want to extract the following information from the first first two lines:

e.g this is the sequence first word is journey---
then brackets will contain two words, ----
then word from ---
and then it could be word station or city ---
and then again any string ---
then again word to ---
and then it could be word station or city---

What would be the regular expression for that?
Note: Words in brackets may contain special characters e.g -,_

Comment: Please edit the question to show sample data and the code you have tried so far. Otherwise I am afriad that you will not get any help.

Comment: What kind of regex do you want? What are you going to use it for: _search_ for strings that look like this, or _parse_ strings that look like this (i.e. split the string into `(a, b, station, station, c, d)`)?

Comment: I want to first search the complete line in this format as there are many other lines in other sequence i want only this sequence

Comment: I forgot to ask in my earlier comment, but please show us your attempt at solving this problem. This sounds like a fairly simple regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return the elements you want:

```
import re

s = '''journey (a,b) from station south chennai to station punjab chandigarh
journey (c,d) from station jammu katra to city punjab chandigarh
journey (e) from station
journey (c,d) from station ANYSTRING jammu katra to ANYSTRING city punjab chandigarh
'''

matches_single = re.findall('journey (\([^,]+,[^,]+\)) from (\S+ \S+\s{0,1}\S*) to (\S+ \S+\s{0,1}\S*)', s)
for match in matches_single:
    print(match)
matches_line = re.findall('(journey \([^,]+,[^,]+\) from \S+ \S+\s{0,1}\S* to \S+ \S+\s{0,1}\S*)', s)
for match in matches_line:
    print(match)
```

Comment: Hi it is giving ('(a,b)', 'station south chennai', 'station punjab chandigarh')
('(c,d)', 'station jammu katra', 'city punjab chandigarh') not complete line starting from journey and also please tell how u are defining that either station or city word should be there

Comment: Also if i give line journey (c,d) from station jammu katra string to city punjab chandigarh it should not come in result means exact two words should be there after from station|city and to city|station

Comment: Hi it is giving ('(a,b)', 'station south chennai', 'station punjab chandigarh')
('(c,d)', 'station jammu katra', 'city punjab chandigarh') not complete line starting from journey and also please tell how u are defining that either station or city word should be there as when i give <<journey (a,b) from tree south chennai to station punjab chandigarh>> it comes in result it should not come as i have placed <<tree>> in place of station or city

Comment: If I summarize out of these <<journey (a,b) from station south chennai to station punjab chandigarh>>
<<journey (c,d) from city jammu katra to city punjab chandigarh>>
<<journey (c,d) from station jammu katra to city punjab chandigarh>>
<<journey (c,d) from city jammu katra to station punjab chandigarh>>
<<journey (c,d) from ANYSTRING jammu katra to ANYSTRING punjab chandigarh>>
<<journey (c,d) from ANYSTRING jammu ADDITIONALSTRING katra to ANYSTRING punjab chandigarh>>
<<journey (e) from station '''>> it should give first 4 lines

Comment: I have now added also an option to show the complete line instead. You are very unclear about the questions your are asking. It is extremely hard to understand what you want.

Comment: I am sorry for missing things but last thing still missed as have mentioned in previous comment exact two words after <<from>> as i have inserted anystring and it is showing it in result, <<journey (c,d) from station ANYSTRING jammu katra to ANYSTRING city punjab chandigarh>> it should not give this line in result.

Comment: How would you find the anystring? What is different in that string to the other strings? Do you have a list of possible station names? Also please edit the question to make your example and the wanted result more readable!

Comment: here anystring is extra only two words should be there after from station|city and before <<to>> that is what am saying it should not come in results as <<anystring>> is extra word here, there should be only two words after like from station|city  word1 word2 to station|city word3 word4

Comment: And how would you know whether anystring or the string after are the station names?

Comment: what am saying is after from city word1 word2 to city in case there is one more word3 that line should not come in result   example                                      journey (a,b) <<from station>> word1 word2<<to station>> word1 word2
journey (a,b) <<from station>> word1 word2 word3<<to station>> word1 word2 , second line should not come in result

Comment: I know! But how would you know which of the words is the city or station and which one is unwanted?

Comment: it will be in sequence only, only two words should be there line contatining 3 word before <<to>> and after from station/from city should not come in result

Comment: I have updated the program to find only lines with two or three words (including the word `station`) after from and to. This also catches your newest clarification.