# Regular expression in python string

Tags: python, regex

I want to find lines in text file which follows certain order of words.
Example:

```
customer is given as per below
customer are given not priority below
given given below customer
below customer information given
```

I tried this `(?=.*customer)(?=.*given)(?=.*below)` but dint work.

It should give only

```
customer is given as per below 
customer are given not priority below
```

I want the order to be the same:
"customer" at first place and "given" at third place and "below" should be at sixth position.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works:

```
import re

s = '''customer is given as per below
customer are given not priority below
given given below customer
below customer information given
customer is given not as per below'''

matches = re.findall('customer \S+ given \S+\s\S+ below', s)
for match in matches:
    print(match)
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It is exactly what the author wanted...

Comment: Hi mr carnivore, it works but when i give but if am giving                  
               <<customer is given not as per below>>                                                 
                                                                                                                   it is giving this in match as well i want position to be fixed like in this sentence <<below>> is moved to 7th position but i want it to be at 6th position only

Comment: So what exactly should have been the response you wanted in that case?

Comment: It should not come in result as position of three words should be fixed                 <<customer>> at first position, <<given>> at third position, and <<below>> at sixth position

Comment: Write exactly what the result should be!

Comment: Input lines <<customer is given as per below>>
<<customer are given not priority below>>
<<given given below customer>> <<customer is given not as per below>>----------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                               
  result should be --<<customer is given as per below>><<customer are given not priority below>>

Comment: Wow I would recommend thinking about phrasing your question. You mean you only want to return a line if 'customer' is the first word, 'given' is the third word and 'below' is the 6th word in a line?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: I have updated my answer to also match that new requirement.

Comment: Thanks mrcarnivore.. Also can u please explain the answer why \S and \s means how you are doing so many words in between

Comment: can u please tell me regular expression for finding customer(John, Smith) is  below means customer followed by bracket and then any word comma follwoed by any word then 3rd place below

Comment: Ask a new question for that. You did not accept my answer nor upvoted it.

Comment: Accepted it am asking new question as m not able to ask new question, i asked same in my unanswered question if you can please answer there

Comment: Link for answering https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47283657/python-regular-expression-from-file